# How to determine the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^\alpha\int_0^x f(t) dt$, for $f \in L^p[0,1]$?

Tags: limits, lp-spaces

Let $p\geq 1$ and $f\in L^p[0,1]$. For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ determine $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^\alpha\int_0^x f(t) \, dt$.

This problem probably has several cases, but I'm having trouble to determine those cases.

Comment: Consider three cases: $\alpha>-1$, $\alpha=-1$ and $\alpha<-1$.

Comment: One easy case is when the conjugate Holder exponent of p is larger than  $-\alpha$.

Comment: I meant inverse of conjugate actually, hmm maybe is worse condition.

Comment: I suppose we have to use l'hospital rule on $$\frac{\int_0^x f(t) \, dt}{x^{-\alpha}}$$